# Strangers ID's in elements when save an .ai file as SVG in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg, html, save

I have a map of a floor with offices in it in Illustrator, and I need to add to each office drawn an ID to work with it in JavaScript. But the names of the offices have numbers and/or special characters, such "()" and "+" (i.e. "360 (IVO+IMR+IEC)"),and when I save it as a SVG file, the IDs looks like "id='_x33_60__x28_IVO_x2B_IMR_x2B_IEC_x29_'".
Any idea of why happen this? How can I fix it or avoid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For futures references, I resolved this adding a space with the space key at the begin of the ID (for some reason Illustrator prints me something like "_x33_60" if the ID was "360", while with the space at the beginning  i.e. " 360" prints "_360") and deleting the non-alphanumeric characters.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like some of the characters in your file name are being turned into their unicode representation.  For example, the character '3' in unicode is '\x33', and your corrupt file name shows'*x33*'.  Also, '(' in unicode is '\x28', etc, etc.  This seems to not be coincidental.

I don't know what operating system you are running, but maybe you can check your settings for character display, language, or region, as this seems to be a character display problem on your system.  Hope you can get it solved.

Here's a chart of unicode characters, if you're interested:

http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?utf8=string-literal&unicodeinhtml=hex

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The OS is Windows 8.1, in spanish. Illustrator is in spanish too. I will check the properties and configuration of Illustrator.